# Is it possible to open only one specific link within a browser within a WebView android app?

Tags: android, webview

I've been trying to dabble in Android apps recently, and I created a simple web view app that opens my website. Everything works as intended, and I was able to get the links to open within the app itself from the code below.

```
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, String url) {
        return false;
    }
```

I was curious if I could only open a specific link in the browser, however?

I attempted to use

```
if (url.equals("my url here")) {
          //
}
```

inside of the method I provided above, but I couldn't figure out what to call inside my if statement. I've tried to look online a bit, but most of the methods I've found seem to be deprecated.

I want the URL I define to open within the default browser, but everything else is opened within the app.

Thanks for any help you may give!

Edit: WebViewClientImpl class

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;


public class WebViewClientImpl extends WebViewClient {

    private Activity activity = null;
    private android.content.Context Context;

    public WebViewClientImpl(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, String url) {
        if (url.equals("my url here")) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(i);

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's quite possible.  Something like this should do it:

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, String url) {
    if (url.equals("my url here")) {
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(i);

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Note that you'll return `true` in the case of loading the URL via the browser to cancel loading it in your WebView.

Comment: Thank you! I tried something similar to this, but I'm receiving a "cannot resolve method startActivity(android.content.Intent)" error. I believe that means my current class has no access to a context? I'm a bit confused how to fix that problem. I edited my question given the class I used if needed :) Thank you so much.

Comment: Yeah, if you call it from within an Activity it'll work.  One way or another, depending on how your code is structured, you'll want to call `startActivity` on the context of the Activity that's running.  Activities are Contexts, which is why it just works if the code is called from within an Activity.

Comment: My WebViewClient is an inner class within my Activity, so I just call `startActivity` -- but you can do it another way; you just need the Activity context.

Comment: Darshan, you're amazing thank you! I just wanted to add for some odd reason the url.equals function is not properly working. I switched it over to url.contains and used the tail end of my link which works perfectly. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;


public class WebViewClientImpl extends WebViewClient {

   Context context;

    public WebViewClientImpl(Context context1) { //pass activity here 
        this.context= context1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, String url) {
        if (url.equals("my url here")) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            context.startActivity(i);

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

If you are still in confusion just put this class into activity.